How to prove the relation between second cofactor and first cofactor of a matrix
I'm a theoretical chemist and encountered a problem about the determinant relation below.
Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. How to prove the relation
$$
|A|A(ij,kl)=A(i,k)A(j,l)-A(j,k)A(i,l)
$$
where

$|A|$ is the determinant of matrix $A$,
$A(ij,kl)$ denotes the second cofactor of matrix $A$ having removed $i$th and $j$th rows, $k$th and $l$th columns,
$A(i,k)$ denotes the (first) cofactor of matrix $A$ having removed $i$th row and $k$th column, and the others are similar,
$i<j,k<l$.

I wonder if the generalized Laplace expansion could help.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Take a look at the Desnanot-Jacobi identity.

Thank you so much. It helps to the problem. @blargoner
